# How to fix flickering effect during scrollX movement in jQuery DataTables on mobile devices?

Tags: datatables

I have used below code to simulate fixed header with vertical and horizontal scroll bars. See [example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj2ce2pe/).

```
$('#liveTable').dataTable({
      'bSort': false,
      'destroy': true,
      'aoColumns': [
                    { sWidth: "85px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false },
                    { sWidth: "75px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false },
                    { sWidth: "80px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false },
                    { sWidth: "80px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false },
                    { sWidth: "85px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false },
                    { sWidth: "70px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false },
                    { sWidth: "70px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false },
                    { sWidth: "50px", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false }
                ],
      'scrollY': 200,
      'scrollX': true,
      'info': false,
      'paging': false
 });
```

The above code is working fine in Desktop.

But in mobile devices when I scroll body of the content header part not moving accordingly. There is some delay (flickering effect) in header movement in mobile devices.

How to fix that header movement issue in mobile devices?

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicate questions, update the original question instead.

Comment: There is a [way to attract more attention to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).